# Error message in R when attempting to retrieve results of matchit

Tags: r

Can someone please help.

I am using the R package `MatchIt` for propensity score matching.  I was able to match my treatment and control groups by using the following 2 lines of code:

m.out = matchit (Group ~ Gender + Ethnicity + SES, data = mydata, method = "nearest", ratio =1)

summary (m.out)

I want to access my matched data so I can analyze it in excel.  But when I use the following code I get an error message:

Outdata <- match.data (m.out)

I get the following error message:

Error: could not find function "match.data"

Thank you, 
NJ

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the "MatchIt" package loaded:

```
library(MatchIt)
```

Usually that error pops up when you don't have the required package loaded. Check the [help file](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MatchIt/MatchIt.pdf) if you need more info on the function.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I have loaded "MatchIt".  I reloaded it just to be sure...still getting the error message!

Comment: Can you post the code you're using? It might help debug what you're looking at.